# Windows 10 UWP HTML/Winjs application not receiving onactivated event when started from the Sharing charm

Tags: javascript, win-universal-app, windows-10, winjs

I am currently developing a Windows 10 UWP Using HTML5/WinJS technologies.  I would like the application to be a share target for PDF. I have included this in the manifest,

```
  <Extensions> 
    <uap:Extension Category="windows.shareTarget"> 
      <uap:ShareTarget Description="Test Share Target"> 
        <uap:SupportedFileTypes> 
          <uap:FileType>.pdf</uap:FileType> 
        </uap:SupportedFileTypes> 
      </uap:ShareTarget> 
    </uap:Extension> 
  </Extensions>
```

And I have this in the index.js

```
  var app = WinJS.Application; 
  var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation; 
  app.onactivated = function (args) { 
      console.log("app.onactivated"); 
      if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) { 
          console.log("launch"); 
      if (args.detail.previousExecutionState !== activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) { 
          // TODO: This application has been newly launched. Initialize your application here. 
          console.log("newly launched"); 
      } else if (args.detail.kind === Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivationKind.shareTarget) { 
          var shareOperation = args.detail.shareOperation; 
          console.log(JSON.stringify(shareOperation, null, 4)); 
          } else 
      { 
        // TODO: This application has been reactivated from suspension. 
        // Restore application state here. 
      } 
      args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll().then(function() { 
        // TODO: Your code here. 
      }));
```

When I start the application from inside Visual Studio 2015/debugging build directly on a windows phone, I see the expected output with console logging. I can also select a PDF file, and share it to my application, and it starts – but I don't see any console output at all reflected in VS2015. I am looking for the output of   console.log(JSON.stringify(shareOperation, null, 4));

If looked with Google and on Microsoft's site for specific Windows 10 UWP samples, but cannot find anything, I have only found fragments of information.

It seems like my application is not receiving the onactivated event when started from the Sharing charm.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed, Your if-statement of

```
(args.detail.kind === Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivationKind.shareTarget)
```

is currently included in the if-statement of

```
(args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch)
```

So your if-statement of 'shareTarget' won't be executed unless a 'Launch' action of your app.

You should extract it out like:

```
if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
        console.log("launch");
        if (args.detail.previousExecutionState !== activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {
            // TODO: This application has been newly launched. Initialize your application here. 
            console.log("newly launched");
        }
} else if(args.detail.kind === Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivationKind.shareTarget) {
        var shareOperation = args.detail.shareOperation;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(shareOperation, null, 4));
}
```

Here is a Demo I made that you can refer to: [Share Target Sample](https://github.com/elvisxia/StackOverFlowDemos/tree/master/ShareSample)